# How to get 301 redirect from domain to sub-folder (/en) to work properly with htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to get my domain to redirect to my **/en** sub-folder and it seems to work, but it keeps using **302** instead of **301**.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/en$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Quick tip: change `$1` to `/$1` as the `/` is not captured in the rule.

Comment: If **en** is a subfolder and **$1** is a file, then you need to seperate them by  a / , otherwise the path is invalid IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Ok, I made that **/en/$1** change.  I don't think there are any other redirects that conflict with this.  Is there a way to see the directory of the htaccess file being used to load the page?